# php preg replace &num= and &amp;num=

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am not good at writing php regex, now some data like `searchword&num=10` I want use preg replace remove `&num=10` or sometimes it could be `&amp;num=10`, thanks.

```
echo preg_replace(array('/\&num=(d+)/i','/(&amp;)num=(d+)/i'),'','searchword&num=10');
//I would like to only get searchword
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to your advantage here.

```
$searchStr = html_entity_decode($searchStr);
echo preg_replace('/\&num=\d+/i', '', '$searchStr);
```

Although, you can simply use substr like this

```
echo substr($searchStr, strpos('&'));
```

Comment: I do like first solution, not by `strpos` or `/^[^\&]+/`, some search word could contain `&amp;`, should avoid killing them.

Comment: If that is a possibility, then html_entity_decode would work fine for you.

Answer (score 1):

What about a regex that will match anything from the beginning of the string up to the first ampersand ?

```
/^[^\&]+/
```